# Mysterious Circle of missing varnish on newer dressor

Tags: wood, wooden-furniture

[image][image]

Can anyone tell me what is going on here? On stumped.  This is the side of a 7 drawer dresser. The side shown faces nothing but a wall and for the four years that I've had this piece it has literally never even seen sun. My father suggested that something peed on it, but I highly doubt that especially given the fact that my dog doesn't pee in my house and also the perfect circular shape. It's almost like something is eating away at the Varnish in this one little spot.

Comment: My guess would be a mold or fungus. They can grow radially into a circle.

Comment: Since its on the side and round other than a mold or fungus that Mathew suggested is there a heat source?

Comment: No heat source whatsoever.  A mold or fungus would be shocking, though I admit I don't know anythig about how something like that would spawn.  I live in an urban area on the 4th floor of a building.  I have a dog but I don't think he had anything to do with this.  I use a steam mop in my house, but I sort of eliminated that as the cause given the fact no other pieces of this bedroom set exposed in the same way to the mop has emerged with this marking.

Comment: I just used the furniture cleaner and then polish that the furniture came with.  As you can see in the picture the wood here has become textured and a bit raised.  The cleaner leveled that down a bunch which makes me think it was either something on the wood, or the varnish or clear coat is what was raised and I was just able to remove that.  Either way its flatter now but there is still a perfect circle demarcation in the wood like something stamped it.  So strange. This is a spot in the wood where it forms a knot, if thats any help.

Comment: Looks like cases where I've seen varnish delaminate from the wood's surface. What is this dresser made of? Is it solid wood or is it particle board or plywood with a veneer? You mention a knot, which isn't visible from that picture. If there is a veneer and there is a knot under it, that could easily cause the veneer and/or varnish to delaminate from the surface.

Comment: I don't know how to tell veneer from solid wood.  Its not laminate.  Its very heavy.  It was purchased at an upper-end furniture store. I really think its solid wood.  What causes varnish to delaminate, and why would it do it in a perfect circle?

Comment: Something spilled on the wood (oil, sillicone, etc) at the factory, not cleaned properly, then the varnish doesn't adhere properly.

Comment: Its by Bernhardt and its solid Mahogany bought in 2012, if that helps.  I wouldn't say there is a knot upon second look.  The wood just has more striations near this mystery spot that in other spots.  I wish you could post more than two pics on this thread!

Comment: @KjSATX if you wish to have more pictures upload them to imgur.com (no account needed there for this, although they do have that option) paste the links to the pics here in a comment and someone with more rep than you can add them above for you.